# Converting to and exporting String

Tags: java, string

Hey I cannot figure out how to return the type as a String as I have defined the outputGrade as a String but I am trying to calculate the single number. e.g- mark=79 then outputGrade string = "9"

```
private static String printResult (int numAssignments, double  studentMark)
        {
        int outputGradeSingle;
        String outputGrade;
        switch (numAssignments)
        {
        case 0:  outputGrade="DNA-";
        break;
        case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: outputGrade="DNC-";
        break;
        case 5: if (studentMark<50.0)
                {
                outputGrade="F-";
                }
                else
                {
                outputGradeSingle=(studentMark/10);
                outputGrade= String.valueOf(outputGradeSingle);
                }
        break;
        default: outputGrade="Not a valid amount of assignments, range is between 0 and 5";
        break;
        }
        return outputGrade;
        }
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?  What error indication do you get??

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are assigning a `double` to an `int` and you get a `possible loss of precision` error. Just explicitly cast the result `int` and you should be fine (assuming you are ok with the decimals being truncated):

```
outputGradeSingle = (int) (studentMark / 10);
```

Note: you state

> mark=79 then outputGrade string = "9"

if `mark` is 79, `outputGrade` will be `7` with your code.

Comment: Thank you, I literally just worked that out and added it to my code! 
But thank you very much for responding.

Comment: @RandomPerson Does it solve your problem or do you have another issue?